# Refresh all entries in Caffeine / Scaffeine

Tags: java, scala, caching, caffeine

I'm working with the Scala version of [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), [Scaffeine](https://github.com/blemale/scaffeine).
I'm trying to populate a cache, in a way that it should reload all the values after expiration (10sec in the test). I probably I could use Guava's `Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration` but I'd like to take the advantage of the asynchronous loading of data in the background.
I have the following snippet:

```
val dummy = List()
val myCache: AsyncLoadingCache[String, String] =
  Scaffeine()
    .refreshAfterWrite(10.second)  //test
    .buildAsyncFuture(
      loader = userId => client.getByUserId(userId),
      allLoader = Some(dummy => client.getAllUsers),
      reloadLoader = None)
```

I'd thought that `allLoader` is for this purpose, but it's called only once during cache construction time, and only those values are populated for which the keys are enumerated in the "dummy" list.

There's a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534666/prefetch-all-entries-in-java-caffeine-cache) thread which suggests to implement `CacheLoader#loadAll` but any hint would be great how to implement this 
possibly in Scala with Scaffeine?

Comment: Perhaps a problem is that refresh is per-key and [batch refresh](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/issues/7) is not yet implemented. If you always want the full list then adapting `memoizeWithExpiration` is probably cleaner. You might use a scheduling thread to refresh, since both Guava and Caffeine reload on the first stale call (so may be dated if low activity).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!